# Powershell confirm folder existence and sending an email if it does not

Tags: python, powershell

I am trying to search a SQL database to confirm if a directory exists. If the directory does not exist the script should send off an email for notification. I have attempted to create something but I am not well versed in PowerShell.

I am able to get all of the data from our SQL server. I am running into an error with $($Row.[Last Name]). It states that it is unable to find [Last Name] type, but it finds Account and IsActive just fine.

Unable to find type [Last Name]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At \cottonwood\users\CB\My Documents\SQLserver-search.ps1:44 char:17
+ $Row.[Last Name] <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Last Name:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

I'm not sure if my question is clear or not. I'm new to Stack Overflow. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Param (
    $Path = "\\cottonwood\users\Shared\Pool Acquisitions",
    $SMTPServer = "generic-mailserver",
    $From = "generic-outbound-email",
   #The below commented out line is used to test with just one individual. Be sure to comment out the one with all individuals before troubleshooting.
    #$To = @("generic-email"),
    $port = "587",
    $To = @("generic-inbound-email"),
    $Subject = "Folders Added in",
    $logname = "\\cottonwood\users\Shared\Loan Documents - Active\logs\New Folders$date.txt",
    $date = (Get-Date -Format MMddyyyy),
    $SMTPBody = "`nThe following Pool Acquisitions folders have been added in the last 24 hours:`n`n"
)


$SQLServer = "REDWOOD" #use Server\Instance for named SQL instances! 
$SQLDBName = "MARS"
$SqlQuery = "select Account, IsActive, [Last Name] FROM vw_loans WHERE LEFT(Account,1)<>'_' ORDER BY Account"

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)


$SqlConnection.Close()

clear

$DataSet.Tables[0]

foreach ($Row in $dataset.Tables[0].Rows) { 
    write-Output "$($Row)"
    write-Output "$($Row.Account)"
    write-Output "$($Row.IsActive)"
    write-Output "$($Row.[Last Name])"
}

if($Row.IsActive -eq $True){
$ChkPath = "U:\Shared\Loan Documents - Active\$Row.Account - $Row.[Last Name]"
}
else{
$ChkPath = "U:\Shared\Loan Documents - Inactive\$Row.Account - $Row.[Last Name]"
}

$FileExist = Test-Path $ChkPath

$SMTPMessage = @{
    To = $To
    From = $From
    Subject = "$Subject $Path"
    Smtpserver = $SMTPServer
    Port = $port
}

If($FileExist -eq $True) {Write-Host "Null Response"}
else
{    $SMTPBody = "Loan folder is missing. Please advise."
    $LastWrite | ForEach { $SMTPBody += "$($_.FullName)`n"  }
   UseSSL = $true
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It would help if you could clarify what is/isn't working for you in your existing script, and what you expect the behaviour to be.

Comment: You mention a sql database but the script doesn't seem to access anything like that.

Comment: I've ran into a couple of errors. If I kill one I get another. This is my current error.

Send-MailMessage : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Port'.
At C:\Folder Scanner\foldertesting.ps1:36 char:21
+     Send-MailMessage <<<<  @SMTPMessage -Body $SMTPBody 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

Comment: It's telling you that Send-MailMessage doesn't have a Port parameter, which you're trying to bind to it via your $SMTPMessage hashtable, take that line out and try replacing it with UseSSL = $true

Comment: I did some editing to the body and I'm having some new issues now.

Comment: Replace the square brackets with quote marks: $Row.'Last Name'

Comment: Thank you! I made the change to that now I am having an issue with the UseSSL cmdlet.

The term 'UseSSL' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At \\cottonwood\users\Cameron.Byers\My Documents\SQLserver-search.ps1:68 char:10
+    UseSSL <<<<  = $true
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (UseSSL:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Remove that line from your code. It should be in the $smtpmessage block, but that part is redundant now as you seem to have removed send-mailmessage.

Comment: I realized I read your comment wrong earlier and I made the correct modifications. I now have a service not available error that I will have to fix on my end.

Comment: This has gone way past the remit of a single SO question FYI, I recommend you read the getting started guide to better engage with SO in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`if($Activity = 'y')` should be `if($Activity -eq 'y')`

In PowerShell `=` always sets a value so this statement is always true.

I'm also pretty sure `param` blocks have to be at the top of a script.

Comment: *I'm also pretty sure param blocks have to be at the top of a script.* You are correct sir! The only thing that is allowed before a script's parameters are the comment based help if any exists, and the `[cmdletbinding()]` info if that is desired.